# Convert API resource to array

Tags: laravel, google-cloud-firestore

I want to store data on Firestore. I need to send an array to Firestore. I have API resources and I wanted to use it.

My ApiResource:

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'name' => $this->name,
        'phone' => $this->phone,
        'addresses' => AddressResource::collection($this->addresses),
    ];
}
```

Firestore store data:

```
public function set(User $user){
    $this->firestore->document($user->id)->set((new UserResource($user)));
}
```

It is an error:

> Argument 1 passed to
>   Google\Cloud\Firestore\DocumentReference::set() must be of the type
>   array, object given,...

Comment: This code does not make sense i context of api resources, you set an empty array and don't include it.

Comment: Which part doesn't make sense? Be specific!

Comment: `set([]);` doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thank you for your remind. I forgot to add resource here. Now I updated my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the `toJson()` on your Api Resource object:

```
$data = MyModel::with('addresses')->find(1);

$myArray = json_decode((new MyModelResource($data))->toJson(), true);
```

So you could just:

```
$this->firestore->document($user->id)->set($myArray);
```

Comment: I got this error:
`Too few arguments to function App\\Http\\Resources\\MobileApi\\UserResource::toArray()`

Comment: @MaksatMeredow glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Do it:

```
public function set(User $user){
    $this->firestore->document($user->id)->set(toArray($user)); 
}
```

Comment: I wanted to use ApiResources. I updated my code. Please check one time my code